# Django 2, No module named error when trying to import my own modules

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Django and I have an issue when I try to import my own module in views.py. I'm actually using Pycharm IDE. You will see below the structure of my project I want to use some class which are in IOCVisualizeEntities project in views.py. I read that I must declare the  IOCVisualizeEntities application in INSTALLED_APPS (in settings.py) like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'IOCVIsualizeView.apps.IocvisualizeviewConfig',
    'IOCVIsualizeEntities',
...
]
```

but I have the error 'No module named 'IOCVIsualizeEntities' where I run the server.

Thanks for your help,

[image: project structure]

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't say hello...:)

Comment: to create an application in a django project you have to run the command python manage.py startapp yourappname

Comment: Thx Dimitri but it's not an app, it's a class library I want to use in my django app.

Comment: You don't need to add class libraries that are not Django apps to `INSTALLED_APPS`, you can just import them as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, the module's name is `IOCVisualizeEntities`, but you have `IOCVIsualizeEntities` in the quoted snippet (i.e. a difference in character case).

Comment: Oh! I knew about case sensitive in python but I didn't see it! thanks It's working :). A new eye is always good :). I spent two nights on this... Thanks agin :)